# How to compress 'odd/even number of times'?

Tags: single-word-requests

If A occurs exactly *two* times, one could say "A occurs *twice*."
If A occurs exactly *three* times, one could say "A occurs *thrice*." etc.

Not being a native English speaker, I don't know how to properly name these words that compress the expression for "number of occurences", however, I've found articles online that have expanded their realm of existence beyond the numerals of 1, 2 and 3, such as "septence" for 7, etc.

I wonder if there are 'compression words' like this for "odd" and "even number of times". I would find these words extremely useful. There are words like that in Czech, I am however unable to find their English equivalents. Do they exist?

Comment: What are these Czech words? That might help others in a search.

Comment: @Kate Thank you for your clarification, however, this is not a practical, but a theoretical question. I respect - but do not care much about - what words are commonly used. I am simply looking for what the question states.

Comment: In Czech, words for "odd" and "even" (in the context of numbers) are "*sudý*" and "*lichý*" respectively, and a "times"-equivalent suffix exists, "*-krát*", used in "five" = "pět", "five times" = "pětkrát", and so on, therefore, we can use "*sudokrát*" and "*lichokrát*" for expressing "odd/even number of times".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth this question asks if there's such a word for odd and even, not for higher numbers.

Comment: @JJ Finally, thank you, the first person in this post that realizes what the question is asking. Probably my mistake, if only you got it, I must have terrible expressive skills.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Kind sir, would you please reopen the question? (or try to answer it yourself?) It is clearly not a duplicate of the one you have associated with it.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan the people on here are a bit frustrated, eager to close things. Most others, including me, aren't really active here anymore. I'm not sure, but you might be better off asking at [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JJ Thank you for the suggestion, I am migrating out of here.

Comment: 'X occurs an odd number of times' cannot be expressed *'X is oddnumerate';  *'X occurs oddwise' etc. Though 'oddly' is a word, it means 'peculiarly'.  There is no single-word term for 'X occurs _an even number of times_' either. *_paritous/ly_. To the best of my knowledge; I taught maths to Oxbridge entrance level.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for answering! I would expect this to be an actual answer, and not just a comment, so others can see it immediately as well, but I appretiate it anyway. If what you're saying is true, that would be very unfortunate. As a respectable math teacher, your opinion is most likely valid, but I cannot give up my search yet.

Comment: The normal use is thus: The series repeats twice”; “The series repeats three times” “The series repeats an even/odd number of times.” With sufficient context, we can say: “The series repeats oddly/evenly.”; Or “The series is odd/even.” Czech is an fusional synthetic language, but English is an analytic language, hence the difference.

Comment: @Greybeard How about the suffix "-fold"? Does it help my case? As in "The line intersects the polygon *oddfold*."

Comment: Can you find it in a dictionary? (The answer "No, but that doesn't prove that it's never been used that way" is trumped by "But it does show it's at best a very rare usage, and one would be very wise to avoid it even if it's been worded.")

Comment: @Captain Trojan - unfortunately, it does not. "Oddfold" and "evenfold" do not exist as words in English. "Fold" is qualified only by a number or quantifier.

Comment: @Chenmunka Thats where I have been directed after this question was closed for unjustified duplicity, looking for answers at a forum advertised as "containing less frustrated, less eager to close things off people".

Comment: Having said that "evenfold/oddfold" did not exist and would not exist - I now find that they do exist, but, it appears, only in the rarefied context of advanced mathematics: ">"Non-linear Optics in Metals" edited by K. H. Bennemann

>The analysis is performed for films with an **even-fold** rotation symmetry as well as for those with an **odd-fold** one. [...]the thin garnet films,[...] have **even-fold** rotation symmetry [...] while those grown on (Ill) faces have the **odd-fold** rotation symmetry." However, I would caution against using these terms unless addressing mathematicians.

Comment: @Greybeard sometimes mathematicians must define their own words for convenience. Thank you for researching this for us, I will never use this term in a non-mathematical text. You are more than welcome to extract a legit answer from this and I will happily accept it.

EDIT: Oh my bad, Mr. Ashworth did not unblock this question (yet), either being unable to do so or still believing that this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with Kate:  "Thrice" is so infrequently used that I would say it was not colloquial.

I am reminded of the old Lionel Ritchie song, "Three Times a Lady"

*You're once twice
Three times a lady
And I love you
Yes your once twice
Three times a lady
And I love you
I love you*

Note:  The copied lyrics probably contain an error.  The "your" almost certainly should have been written "you're".

Comment: I have changed the words "would" to "could" in my example so that people don't mistake my opinion on the word "thrice" as "I believe that 'thrice' is a common word." instead of "I believe that  'thrice', as a word, exists and people are free to use it." I appretiate your interest in my question, but I would love if you would shed some light on the topic at hand.

Comment: I'm not sure that lyrics can be a good basis for saying something is or isn't. Consider Dylan's _Don't Think Twice, It's Alright_: "And it ain't no use in a-turnin' on your light, babe // The light I never knowed".